# Sp List item versions using REST

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, version

Is it possible to retrieve all versions of list items using REST? or at-least any other way of achieving it using javascript/jquery?

I have followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423657/sharepoint-2013-get-splistitem-versions-via-rest article and there is a answer using version page but i am not able to retrieve the field values from the response i get from that solution. I just get `Object`as a response

Answer (score 3):

```
/_api/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/Items(1)/versions
```

Comment: Not working. Are you sure it is valid API?

Comment: yep, works for me.

Comment: 2013 on prem didn't have this when first shipped. It works for SharePoint online, but I don't know if it became available on prem with 2019, or 2016, or 2013 +some service pack?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you write `versionEntries` to the console. It is an object. If you are using IE, it will display as object instead of data in console. You can try using Chrome and check the console output value, it will display data from the object.

You can also try to use the SharePoint List web service that exposes [Lists.GetVersionCollection Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-services/ms774544(v=office.12)) to return version information for an item in a SharePoint list.

Here is a code demo to retrieve a list item version, it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
                $().SPServices({
                                 operation: "GetVersionCollection",
                                  async: false,
                                  strlistID: "Lists_1",
                                  strlistItemID: 1,
                                  strFieldName: "Title",
                                  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                                  console.log(xData);
                                    $(xData.responseText).find("Version").each(function(i) {
                                      console.log("Name: " + $(this).attr("Title") + " Modified: " + $(this).attr("Modified"));
                                    });  
                                  }
                }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a document library instead of a list, use:

```
_api/lists/getbytitle('FooLibrary')/Items(48)/File/Versions
```

Comment: BTW, this works for lists too in SharePoint online.  I don't know which, if any, versions of on prem it works for.