# REST API Item Versions Endpoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, splistitem

In this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242077/sp-list-item-versions-using-rest), it appears there is a "/versions" endpoint for the ListItems  REST API.

`/_api/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/Items(#)/versions` returns a 404 'Not Found' on our SharePoint 2016 On-Premise server.

Is there a Cumulative Update or Feature Pack that introduces this endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API only supports in SharePoint Online, not for on-premises. So, it does not work in SharePoint 2016.

If you want to get version information, you can try to use the SharePoint List web service that exposes [Lists.GetVersionCollection Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-services/ms774544(v=office.12)) to return version information for an item in a SharePoint list.

Here is a code demo to retrieve a list item version, it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
                $().SPServices({
                                 operation: "GetVersionCollection",
                                  async: false,
                                  strlistID: "Lists_1",
                                  strlistItemID: 1,
                                  strFieldName: "Title",
                                  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                                  console.log(xData);
                                    $(xData.responseText).find("Version").each(function(i) {
                                      console.log("Name: " + $(this).attr("Title") + " Modified: " + $(this).attr("Modified"));
                                    });  
                                  }
                }); 
});
</script>
```

Refer to my answer in [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242077/sp-list-item-versions-using-rest).

Here is a demo to get item field version history from Versions.aspx:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/aspnet/en-US/33f9dc3d-be4d-489c-9f40-34aada8c73a2/any-rest-api-available-for-version-history-of-list-item-fileds?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/siteName/Lists/listName/{itemID}_.000')/Versions
```